# Зачем в PHP нужны классы?

Tags: php, ооп

Зачем в PHP нужны классы? Почему нельзя все писать в процедурном стиле, ведь это же проще и кода меньше.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ООП нужен для того, чтобы вы наоборот не писали лишнего кода, когда проект будет большим. И эта парадигма проще в плане чтения кода, в отличии от процедурного подхода.

Вот хорошая статья, которые поможет понять объектно-ориентированное программирование, там как раз примеры на PHP:

http://ru.wh-db.com/article/chto-takoe-objecno-orientirovannoe-programmirovanie/

Answer (score 2):

Для маленьких, любительских проектов выгоды от объектно ориентированного подхода невелики. Но чем больше ваш проект, чем больше правил, зависимостей и специальных случаев вам понадобится держать в голове, чем больше в вашем проекте будет участников и тем самым чем больше будет необходимость уменьшить зависимости между частями кода, тем больше ваш выигрыш от объектно-ориентированного проектирования.

Заметьте, что ООП — это не ключевое слово класс, это дизайн всей программы, построенный таким образом, чтобы внутренние дела каждой сущности оставались внутри этой сущности, и никак не влияли на другие сущности.

А меньше всего кода будет если отказаться от процедур и использовать `goto`. Только какая ваша цель: меньше кода или меньше затраты времени на разработку?